# Nuget powershell command - find projects with specific package installed

Tags: powershell, nuget

I want, via the nuget console, to list project that has a specific package installed.

Ex :

```
get-project -all | get-package | ?{ $_.Id -like 'ThePackage' } | `
    <Here I have all the packages, but I can't access the project name>
```

The last part should be something like `Select-Object project.Name`, but get-package does not return the project name, just the package information.

Comment: I got so confused when I came to this question,  I was like hmm I don't remember asking this question

Comment: I got confused too when I saw that comment, I was like hmm I don't remember leaving this comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, this could be better. One way to do this is to take advantage of the fact that get-package will accept a filter on project:

```
Get-Project | foreach-object {
    get-package -ProjectName $_.Name | `
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ProjectName -Value $_.Name -passthru
    }  | select id, projectname | ft -auto -GroupBy projectname
```

I'm adding the projectname property the each package before grouping on this property at the end.

Edit by Johnny5 :
To get the exact result I wanted, I edited the command like this :

```
Get-Project -all | foreach-object { get-package -ProjectName $_.Name | `
    Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ProjectName -Value $_.Name -passthru
} | where-object { $_.id -eq 'Id.Of.The.Package' } | select id, projectname
```

Comment: `%` is the alias for `ForEach` ?

Comment: Thanks, I acheived what I wanted from your command. It would be nice if you add some explanation on `%` and `Add-Member` command :-)

Comment: The percentage is the `foreach-object` command (you can find this out by running `get-help %`. You can find out about `add-member` with `get-help add-member`.

Comment: I moved the where-object (alias: ?) in front of the select

Answer (score 0):

With version 2.0.0.0 of the Get-Package cmdlet, there is an entry returned for each usage of a package within a project - and the project name is included.

Check your version of Get-Package with the following command in the Package Manager Console within Visual Studio.

```
get-command get-package
```

Find all of the projects that have a specific package installed using the following command.

```
get-package newtonsoft.json
```

If you are interested in finding any packages for which projects within the solution reference different versions, then try the following command. It should display a list of packages. You can choose one, hit OK and it will show you the projects that reference them.

```
get-package | group-object Id | %{$versions = ($_.Group | Group-object Version); if(($versions | measure-object).Count -gt 1){$versions;};} | %{$_.Group} | group-object Id, Version | sort-object Name | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single | %{$_.Group} | select-object -first 1 | %{ $version = $_.Version; get-package $_.Id;} | ?{$_.Version -eq $version}
```